# Perl: foreach line, split, modify the string, set to array. Opendir, next if files=modified string. Unlink files

Tags: perl, if-statement, while-loop, foreach, iteration

I'm having issues with the following block of code: Where $output is netstat -lnt | grep ":::60".  Specifically the section under the comment `#Create filename format`

```perl
my @lines = split /^/, $output;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
 my ($garb, $long_ports)  = (split /\s*:::\s*/, $line);

#Get the last 2 digits of the 60XX port number
 my ($garb2, $ports) = (split /60/, $long_ports);

#Split values to numbers 0-9 for correct filename format
if ($ports < 10) {
  my ($garb3, $ports2) = (split /0/, $ports);

#Add 0 since 0 port is split to empty string
if (length($ports2) == 0){
  $ports2 = "0$ports2";
}

#Create file name format
my @locked_ports = ".X$ports2-lock";
 }
}
 my %h = map {$_ => 1 } @locked_ports;
 #open /tmp and find the .X*-lock files that DO NOT match locked_ports
 opendir (DIR, $tmp ) or die "Error in opening dir $tmp\n";
 while (my $files = readdir(DIR)) {
   if (exists $h{$files}){
   next}
   unlink $files;
 }
   closedir(DIR);
```

I've also tried:

```perl
#Create file name format
my @locked_ports = ".X$ports2-lock";
 }
}
 #open /tmp and find the .X*-lock files that DO NOT match locked_ports
 opendir (DIR, $tmp ) or die "Error in opening dir $tmp\n";
 while (my $files = readdir(DIR)) {
   next if $files =~ @locked_ports;
   unlink $files;
 }
   closedir(DIR);
```

And:

```perl
#Create file name format
my $locked_ports = ".X$ports2-lock";
 }
}
 #open /tmp and find the .X*-lock files that DO NOT match locked_ports
 opendir (DIR, $tmp ) or die "Error in opening dir $tmp\n";
 while (my $files = readdir(DIR)) {
   next if $files =~ $locked_ports;
   unlink $files;
 }
   closedir(DIR);
```

Each time I get an error similar to: `Global symbol "@locked_ports" requires explicit package name`, `Global symbol "$locked_ports" requires explicit package name`

How can I have the while "next" over filenames that equal the lines of locked_ports?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: proper indentation would make it easier to read. but even so I'd advise you to start from scratch. to get help here I would recommend you ditch the code, and just show the input and explain in plain text what you want to do with it.

Comment: The hash code you had but have since removed made more sense `... =~ @foo` is no good.

Comment: Also note that you try to unlink `.` and `..` and other directories.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks,  I will try with the hash approach.  Going to ditch the code like beasy recommended and explain what I need in plain text.

Comment: @beasy noted.  Will do thanks.

Comment: @ikegami would adding `next unless (-f "$tmp/$Xlock");` fix the unlink of `.` and `..` and other directories if $Xlock="X*-lock" ?

Comment: `unlink($files);` => `unlink($files) if !-d $files;` though the only chance of causing harm on linux systems is if the script is run as root, and even then, a flag needs to be turned on.

Comment: Please don't replace your question with a different question. Rolled back. You can see what you wrote [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29396526/7)

Comment: @ikegami sorry new here.  The script will be started with root permissions...

Comment: @ikegami `unlink($files) if !-d $files;` still picks up files that do not have the name syntax `X*-lock`.  How do I specify to only delete files with that name syntax?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Comments are also not the place to ask new questions

Comment: @ikegami ok i'll start a new question I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my` scopes the variable to the inner-most block (curlies) in which it is located.

```
{
   my $foo;
   ...
}

# $foo not accessible here.
```

The block ends on the line after the one where you create the variable. Move the variable's declaration so it has a sufficiently large scope.

Comment: Wow i feel like a dummy.  Moving the declaration to the top of the script eliminated the error.  Still not getting desired result, but getting close.

Thank you!

Comment: Even though this wasn't related to my question, but instead the error messages listed above,  I'm marking this as the answer because I made a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401277/perl-opendir-while-readdir-next-if-hash