# Perl: opendir, while readdir, next if, hash

Tags: perl, unix, hash

I have a directory `$tmp` that contains files with the name syntax `.X*-lock` as well as other plain files and directories.

I compare the contents of `$tmp` with values in a hash table corresponding to `.X*-lock` file names that should NOT be deleted.  I then want the script to delete any, and ONLY `.X*-lock` files that aren't in the hash table.  It cannot delete plain files (non "." files), directories, or `.` & `..`

here's some code:

```
 my %h = map { $_ => 1 } @locked_ports;
 #open /tmp and find the .X*-lock files that DO NOT match locked_ports (NOT WORKING)

opendir (DIR, $tmp ) or die "Error in opening dir $tmp\n";
    while ( (my $files = readdir(DIR)))
    {
      next if((-f $files) and (-d $files));
      next if exists $h{$files};
      #unlink($files) if !-d $files;
        if (! -d $files){print "$files\n"};
     }
      closedir(DIR);
```

As you can see, for now I replaced `unlink` with `print` so I know the proper files are being listed.

Let's say in my `$tmp` dir I have the following files and directories:

```
./
../
cheese
.X0-lock
.X10-lock
.X11-unix/
.X1-lock
.X2-lock
.X3-lock
.X4-lock
.X5-lock
```

But only `.X1-lock` is in the hash table.  Thus I want to print/delete all other `.X*-lock` files, but not the `.X11-unix/` dir, the `cheese` file, or the `.` & `..`

With the above code, it does not print `.` or `..` which is good, but it does print `cheese` and `.X11-unix`.  How can I change it so these are not printed as well?

(note: this is a stem off [Perl: foreach line, split, modify the string, set to array. Opendir, next if files=modified string. Unlink files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396526/perl-foreach-line-split-modify-the-string-set-to-array-opendir-next-if-fil)  I was told to stop asking more questions in the comments so I made a new question.)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's the problem you describe, but keep in mind that `readdir` doesn't return the path to the file, just the filename.  Unless you're current directory is in `$tmp`, you have to prepend the path (`$tmp` here) yourself, like `next if -d "$tmp/$files"`

Comment: @JimDavis Changing the line `next if((-f $files) and (-d $files));` to `next if(-d "$tmp/$files");` did get rid of `.X11-unix/` in the output.  Now I just need to have it ignore all files except those with the name syntax `.X*-lock` as `cheese` is still showing up.  Closer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
opendir (my $dirhandle, $tmp) or die "Error in opening dir $tmp: $!";
while (my $file = readdir($dirhandle)) {
    # skip directories and files in our hash
    next if -d "$tmp/$file" || $h{$file};
    # skip files that don't look like .X###-lock
    next unless $file =~ /
        \A    # beginning of string
        \.    # a literal '.'
        X     # a literal 'X'
        \d+   # 1 or more numeric digits
        -lock # literal string '-lock'
        \z    # the end of the string
    /x; # 'x' allows free whitespace and comments in regex
#   unlink("$tmp/$file");
    print "$file\n"
}
closedir($dirhandle);
```

If you find it more readable, that last conditional could be written as:

```
next if $file !~ /\A\.X\d+-lock\z/;
```

or even:

```
    if ($file =~ /\A\.X\d+-lock\z/) {
    #   unlink("$tmp/$file");
        print "$file\n"
    }
```

Comment: That works! Do you have somewhere you could point me to understand the `/\A\.X\d+-lock\z/;` a little better?  Thanks

Comment: There's [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), but I'll edit the answer to document it a little better.